# Map a class to a generic whose parameter is the same the class's parameter

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a situation where I need a map like this:

```
Map<Class<T>, SomeGeneric<T>>
```

The class containing this map cannot be generic. What I have so far is this:

```
private class Factory {
    Map<Class<? extends Base>, TypedFactory<? extends Base>> map;

    public Factory() {
        map = new HashMap<Class<? extends Base>, TypedFactory<? extends Base>>();
    }

    public <T extends Base> T get(Class<T> clazz, String id) {
        TypedFactory<T> factory = map.get(clazz);

        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new TypedFactory<T>();
            map.put(clazz, factory);
        }

        return factory.get(id);
    }

    private class TypedFactory<T extends Base> {
        Map<String, T> typeMap;

        public TypedFactory() {
            typeMap = new HashMap<String, T>();
        }

        public T get(String id) {
            return typeMap.get(id);
        }
    }

    private class Base {

    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error:

```
error: incompatible types
            TypedFactory<T> factory = map.get(clazz);
                                             ^
  required: Factory.TypedFactory<T>
  found:    Factory.TypedFactory<CAP#1>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Factory.Base declared in method <T>get(Class<T>,String)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Factory.Base from capture of ? extends Factory.Base
1 error
```

Is Java's type system strong enough to handle this use case, or am I SOL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's type system is not strong enough to prove that your particular design pattern is, in fact, type-safe - so you will not be able to do this without throwing an ugly `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or two down, but you can do it.

Just change:

```
TypedFactory<T> factory = map.get(clazz);
```

To:

```
TypedFactory<T> factory = (TypedFactory<T>) map.get(clazz);
```

Since your `Factory` class controls instantiation and storage of the `TypedFactory` instances, the map is provably type safe, so you are fine;  It's just that the Java compiler isn't smart enough to recognize this.